# Color picker layout appearence in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Bootstrap color picker which looks like:

[image]

I don't want to show the highlighted section in the color picker.

Here's my code:

```
$('#color').ColorPicker({
        color: '#0000ff',
        onShow: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
            return false;
        },
        onHide: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
            return false;
        },
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
            $('#ColorCode').val('#' + hex);
            $('#colorSelector').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        }
});
```

Comment: Hey, one of the simplest way could be, give "width: 210px" to "colorpicker" class. This will only show the colored box and scale, and would hide the highlighted box.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/pkyo0t93/1/